# Adding description in the Overview of the generated Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have written a code in Java using eclipse and also generated the Javadoc of that. Now when I open the index.html file, the web page is displayed. I want to add a general description of the code in the Overview of the generated index.html web page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have sensibly placed the code within some base package (`edu.shamik`?), then you can add package-scoped documentation by placing `package-info.java` file there, containing the required documentation. It should probably also work without the package. See more in the official technotes:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#packagecomment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ANT you can modify your *build-impl.xml* file to add the -overview option.
First of all, create a html file with any name and in anywhere of your source tree. I advise *src/overview.html* since it is the standard.
Then, open your *build-impl.xml* and go to the *javadoc-build* target. Find the  and add the property *Overview="src/overview.html"* like in the example below.

```
    <javadoc author="${javadoc.author}" 
     charset="UTF-8" 
     destdir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" 
     Overview="src/overview.html" 
     docencoding="UTF-8"  
     version="${javadoc.version}" 
     windowtitle="${javadoc.windowtitle}">
        <classpath>
            <path path="${javac.classpath}"/>
        </classpath>
        .
        .
        . other elements      
        .
    </javadoc>
```

If you don't use ANT you can try to check in your builder if there is something similar.